# How effective get n bits, starting from startPos from the UInt64 Number

Tags: c#, .net, types

How effective get n bits, starting from startPos from the UInt64 Number.

i know woh get bit by bit, but i want to do in more effective way.

```
    public static ulong GetBits(ulong value, int startPos)
    {
        int mask = 1 << startPos;
        ulong masked_n = value & (ulong)mask;
        ulong thebit = masked_n >> startPos;
        return (ulong)thebit;
    }
```

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: What do you actually want returned here? If your original was, say, `100111001` and you wanted bits 3 bits starting at bit 2, how would you want that returned? as `000011000`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// assuming bit numbers start with 0, and that
// startPos is the position of the desired
// least-significant (lowest numbered) bit

public static ulong GetBits( ulong value, int startPos, int bits )
{
    ulong mask = ( ( 1UL << bits ) - 1 ) << startPos;
    return ( value & mask ) >> startPos;
}
```

Comment: I know this won't be a real improvement, but would it be possible to replace the mask in the return with `( ( ( 1UL<<bits ) - 1 ) << startPos )` so that will be one less variable to initialize?

Comment: @JohnOdom Sure, you could do that. There's really no point though. It won't make the code any faster or smaller (when compiled). All you'd be doing is making it less readable.

Comment: Yeah, which is why I said it won't be a real improvement :P

Answer (score 1):

Ok - so let's say (for sanity's sake, let's talk 8-bits) you have:

```
10101010
```

And you want 3 (*m*) bits starting at bit 2 (*n*). You you'll need a mask like this:

```
source:  10101010
mask:    00011100
&result: 00001000
```

So how to generate the mask? We start with 1 and shift it by the number of bits we want (*m*)

```
start:        00000001
start << 3:   00001000
```

Now we need a three 1's in our mask, so we simply minus one from the last step:

```
00001000 - 1 = 00000111
```

So we almost have our mask, now we just need to line it up by shifting it by 2 (*n*)

```
00000111 << 2 = 00011100
```

And we have our answer